# How to automatically add a sandbox attribute to iframe using JS

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have multiple video players on my site, but they open popup ads, so to block them I use the sandbox attribute, but not all of the players have the sandbox attribute. So I need javascript to automatically add the `sandbox="allow-modals allow-orientation-lock allow-pointer-lock allow-presentation allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-forms` attribute to all iframes on the page.
How can I do this? Help would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all the frames in a page by using [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName), loop over them, and set the attribute of a DOM element by using [Element.setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute):

```
var frames = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
for (var frame of frames) {
    frame.setAttribute("sandbox", "allow-modals allow-orientation-lock allow-pointer-lock allow-presentation allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-forms");
}
```

[jsfiddle example here](https://jsfiddle.net/ve7tjp6L/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this JavaScript code:

```js
const iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');

for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
    iframes[i].setAttribute('sandbox', 'allow-modals allow...');
}
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/vyspiansky/pen/poyjGPX?editors=0010